# I want to create a custom LED segment display. What do I need to study?

Tags: led, pcb-design, pwm, 7segmentdisplay

I want to create and then order a small run of a customized mass-produced LED segment displays for an art project. They will use PWM. It is not much more complex or detailed than a 7 or 16-segment display. But the segment design is different. If I want to design this myself what file format should I be working towards creating? Do I need to plan the pins and internals of the display myself? Are there any examples of what such plans should look like? My understanding is that the inside of a segment display is a sandwich of light diffusers, a one or two sided PCB, and pins.

Are there resistors in there or other electronics? Or is is just LEDS, diffusers and a little routing? I've tried cracking a few apart but it is hard to tell everything that is going on inside.

I do have an EE to help me, but since it's art and I can't pay much I want to do as much of the plan as I can myself and then get advice. But, I'm feeling lost on where to start.

Should I just try making a prototype with resin?

Comment: So, you want us to do your EE's job for free so you don't have to pay him?

Comment: Your question raises lots of questions. Do you just want to light up a handful of leds, or do you want to control them in any way? How big will the display be? Without specifics we can't tell you anything. Draw us a picture, even.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, give him/her a break, nobody pays the artists in the first place, so naturally they don't have any money to pay their EEs with. ;)

Comment: Cracking an egg apart won't tell you how a chicken works.

Comment: Anyway. this question seem to vague, broad and unclear. So voting to close.

Comment: not really understanding the process, then doing as much as you can yourself might be more harmful than helpful if you want to decrease the workload on your EE. It will be more helpful and friendly if you ask him what he thinks should be done and how you can help him.

Comment: Before this gets closed this might help http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/7-segment-display-tutorial.html

Comment: 3-D printing could be used to create your custom aperture mask. The rest is a simple matter of putting some LEDs behind it and a suitable diffuser over it. You should ask for advice at your local maker space.

Comment: This would be a much more practical question if you edited a dimensioned sketch of what you want to make into it, or at least a clear description of the object with its dimensions.  Something you can build as an assembly of through hole or surface mount LEDs with a 3d printed or perhaps epoxy or resin cast diffuser sounds most practical.  Resistors are typically not included as their value depends on the driving circuit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of LED segment displays. The original, or basic type, simply has LEDs with either a common anode or common cathode. These occupy a small pc board with a set of diffusers and an aperture mask on top. The shape of the apertures defines the shape of each segment. This type of display requires external LED drivers, usually comprising transistors to turn the LEDs on and off, and limiting resistors to set the LED currents. A more advanced type, the integrated display, includes an IC which decodes the inputs to provide the appropriate segment pattern, and also drives the LEDs to the required current/brightness levels.

I believe that you will not be able to afford a custom module. You MUST start inquiries NOW to find out both cost/quantity limits and lead time. I can pretty much guarantee that you will not like what you learn.

If you are trying to roll your own, you should stick to a basic type, that is, you should only provide the LEDs, and count on driving them externally. You can use individual LED modules to create your segments if you are willing to make your segments in whatever shape you can find in LEDs. This may well be circular, square, or rectangular, but your choices of segment size will be severely restricted. If you cannot accept these restrictions, you'll need to make tiny little diffusers, and get someone to make aperture masks using high-contrast transparency film. Then you'll need to assemble the LEDs/diffusers into modules, taking care to optically isolate each segment to avoid light from one segment spilling over to another. Then the aperture will be placed on top of the assembly and fixed in place. I don't know how many of these units you want to make, nor how small you're trying for, but I suspect that you're in for a large effort.

If your segments are large (tenths of inches or more in both dimensions), I'd suspect you're better off getting some perfboard and mounting your LEDs on that, then making isolation cells by drilling into something like 1/4 plywood, then placing a diffuser/aperture plate on top.